# Android: If/Else statement makes app crash

Tags: android, null, if-statement

I'm trying to tell if an android int is null by using If/Else

```
public void onClick(View v) {



            EditText min = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maxnum);
            EditText res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.res);



            int myMin = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString());
            int myMax = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());

            String minString = String.valueOf(myMin);
            String maxString = String.valueOf(myMax);

            int f = (int) ((Math.random()*(myMax-myMin+1))+myMin);

            if (minString.equals(""))
            {
                // Do Nothing
            }

            if (maxString.equals(""))
            {
                // Do Nothing
            }



                res.setText(String.valueOf(f));
```

There are no any errors, but when I'm running the app its crashing when im pressing the button.

I'm also trying to use null instead of "":

```
if (minString.equals(null))
{
    // Do Nothing
}

if (maxString.equals(null))
{
    // Do Nothing
}
```

And i have a crash.

Please help me!!!

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: Please post your LogCat output.

Comment: probably Integer.parseInt() that crashes if you try to parse a non number.

Comment: "android int is null". int can not be null

Comment: How to post a logcat output?

Comment: use logcat, e.g in terminal or through eclipse/android studio and edit your question. do you have the correct names on your EditTexts? Set the correct xml?

Answer (score 1):

```
       do if (maxString == null ) 
    {
        // do something 
      }
```

Comment: Then check your integer values and/or editText views. Are you using the correct editTexts ??

Comment: Also, you are writing the code in onClick() method. So usually we compare : if(v== btn1){ // my code here } Give me the error log.

Comment: I'm using  android:inputType="number"

Comment: Anything you write in EditText will give you string. The 'number' property is for keyboard type. copy paste your error Log please.

Comment: just press control,select the line and copy the error log and paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean equals (Object object)
```

Compares the specified object to this string and returns true if they are equal. The object must be an instance of string with the same characters in the same order.

So its returning error so if you want to check if its null then use  `==` operator on the object.

```
if (maxString == null )
```

Use

```
        int myMin = 0;
        int myMax = 0;
        if(min.getText().toString()!="")
        myMin = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString());
        if(max.getText().toString()!="")
        myMax = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());

        String minString = String.valueOf(myMin);
        String maxString = String.valueOf(myMax);

        int f = (int) ((Math.random()*(myMax-myMin+1))+myMin);

        if (minString.equals(""))
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }

        if (maxString.equals(""))
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }
```

Comment: I get the error around

myMin = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

int variables can't be null

If a null is to be converted to int, then it is the converter which decides whether to set 0, throw exception, or set another value (like Integer.MIN_VALUE)

So if you convert int to string again you cannot get null value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  check = input.getText().toString();
 try {
    if (!check.equals("null")) {
        int max = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
        int constant1 = 1;
        int constant2 = 1;
        int nextNumber = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String fibResult = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            fibResult += "F" + count + "=" + nextNumber + "\n";
            constant1 = constant2;
            constant2 = nextNumber;
            nextNumber = constant1 + constant2;
            count++;
        }
        dspResults.setText("\n" + fibResult);
    } else {
        dspResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dspResults.setText("Invalid");
        dspResults.setText(Gravity.CENTER);
        dspResults.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: here check is a string , and its been used as to check for the null value ,
pls help me to give a code which work for Null !

Comment: I am trying to do a simple Fibonacci code with switch statement,
i want to check the given edittext input string value is null or not ,
if not null then if statement code should execute otherwise else statements ,
The if statement code works fine , But if edittext given is empty or null  or "" then it does not executes the else statement ,   
And it crash ,if not put in try block.
How can i make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {



            EditText min = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maxnum);
            EditText res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.res);



            int myMin = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString());
            int myMax = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());

            String minString = String.valueOf(myMin);
            String maxString = String.valueOf(myMax);

            int f = (int) ((Math.random()*(myMax-myMin+1))+myMin);
           {

            if (minString.equals(""))
            {
                // Do Nothing
                 res.setText(String.valueOf(f));
                  return false;

            }

            else if (maxString.equals(""))
            {
                // Do Nothing
                res.setText(String.valueOf(f));
                return false;

            }

             else  
             res.setText(String.valueOf(f));

           return true ; 
       }
```